# How do I create a transition to make something slide in?

Tags: html, css

I'm currently working on a project in HTML and CSS. It requires some kind of navigation menu, which I already created. The menu opens up on clicking a button and it should slide in from the left. Now my problem is that the transition does not work and I have no idea why. It's my first time working with CSS transitions.

Here's the jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Lunaetic/tonqr3gx/ (it's not important that the image of the button cannot be displayed there)

And here the code:

HTML

```
<div class="collapsibleList">
        <label for="box1"><img src="TOPBAR_Icon_Home.png" alt="Menu icon"/></label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="box1" />
        <ul class="menu">
            <li></li>
            <li>Menu item 1</li>
            <li>Menu item 2</li>
            <li>Menu item 3</li>
            <li>Menu item 4</li>
            <li>Menu item 5</li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.menu{
    list-style-type: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: -16px;
    left: -300px;
    max-width: 300px;
    transition: left 1s ease;
    -webkit-transition: left .5s ease;
}

.menu li {
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #ffd012;
    color: #000000;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ffffff;
    padding-left: 55px;
    min-height: 25px;
}

.collapsibleList > input + * {
    display: none;
}

.collapsibleList > input:checked + * {
    display: block;
    left: -40px;
}

.collapsibleList > input {
    display: none;
}

.menu li:last-child {
    border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
    border: none;
}

label {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: fixed;
    left: 10px;
    top: 10px;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Could somebody give me a possible solution to make the menu slide in from the left and tell me why my attempt does not work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you remove this

```
.collapsibleList > input + * {
    display: none;
}
```

the menu slides in.

Comment: I almost gave you a -1 for laziness (not explaining and merely guessing). But hey, tested it in the fiddle and works like a charm. Sometimes the simplest answers are the best ;) +1 for you my friend!

Comment: Thank you, it works! It's always something that simple... I had this in the code because it should not be visible when the checkbox isn't checked, but that's not even necessary anymore when it is positioned outside of the window by default (: